# How recover local branch deleted

Tags: git

I created a local branch and push to server:

```
$ git checkout -b feature
....    
$ git pull origin feature
```

If I deleted this branch:

```
$ git branch -D feature
```

How I recover again this branch from remote server.
I try with:

```
$ git pull
Current branch master is up to date.
$ git branch
* master
```

Answer (score 4):

If you forcefully deleted the branch (or were required to), you likely lost some commits.  (Conversely, `git branch -d <branch>` going through successfully implies that the branch you have is fully merged in.)

If you haven't cleared your terminal yet, you'll see a message like this:

> ```
> Deleted branch feature (was <SHA>).
> ```

Restoring what was originally coming from your remote is simple...

```
git checkout feature
```

The above will automatically create the remote tracking branch.

However, if you need to restore your old branch because there were unmerged changes, you'd need to do a little more.

```
git checkout <SHA>
git checkout -b feature
git branch -u origin/feature
```

The above will:

- Put you in a detached HEAD state
- Create a branch called feature
- Set the branch you're on (at this point, feature) to have an upstream of `origin/feature`

Answer (score 3):

As GianArb said, you can simply checkout the remote branch again, however, if you have made local commits that you didn't push, you don't get them back.

Instead, you can try to locate their hashes back using `git reflog`, then `git checkout $1` where $1 is the potential most recent local commit hash you could find, you will be in a detached HEAD state so you need to branch to a new branch afterwards using `git checkout -b new_branch_name`.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout -b feature origin/feature`

origin is your remote :)